# On Zoom I sound like a chipmunk - Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: sound, microphone

It doesn't happen every time, but quite often when I join a Zoom call, I'm told I sound like a chipmunk. I've tried different microphones, and even switching microphones during the call, but nothing seems to work. Occasionally I can fix it by leaving the call and rejoining.

I've tried recording sound in Ubuntu and it also makes me sound like a chipmunk on a random basis. (I can't seem to find a way to include sound clips here).

I should point out that I am not a chipmunk. I have sound recordings where I sound fine.

Comment: +1 for that last clarification.

Comment: It sounds as if the wrong sampling frequency is used on your microphone. If it happens, try removing the folder `.config/pulse` from your home directory. Even then you may need to restart Zoom.

Comment: try "pulseaudio -k" whenever you have a problem. Sound on Linux is still not completely reliable.

Comment: I'm afraid none of those worked. It does seem to be an interaction between pulse and Zoom. I had a meeting tonight when it happened again - I even restarted my system and it persisted. I had a separate meeting with one other person afterwards, and tried both suggestions, but to no avail.

Comment: I have now found that the "Chipmunk" effect starts when I plug in my USB camera.

Comment: An acquaintance of mine has this problem on Win10, they reboot and it seems to get fixed. It might be a zoom or hardware fault?